# How to enable query logging with Spring Data Redis?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

For Spring Data JDBC I can use `logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE` in order to see what queries are being executed.

What is analogous option for Spring Data Redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/1586 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/1321 there is no way of logging queries besides using `MONITOR` command inside `redis-cli`.